# Qt - How to intercept the application's close event (if there's one)

Tags: c++, events, qt, signals-slots

I need to do some work right before my application closes (note that I said my application and **not** it's main window). Is there an application close event or any other way to accomplish this?

The reason that I can't rely on the main window's close event is that my application runs on the background leaving a system tray icon.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your application is likely derived from `QApplication`. You could put your cleanup code in the destructor of your application:

```
class MyApp: public QApplication {
public:
    ~MyApp() {
        // cleanup code here
    }
};
```

Or, in your `main()`, you probably have something like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    MyApp a(argc, argv);
    return a.exec();
}
```

You can do work after calling `exec()`:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    MyApp a(argc, argv);
    int r = a.exec();
    // cleanup code here
    return r;
}
```

Comment: I'll try the second option. Does this makes the OS show that message "The following applications are blocking the shutdown"?

Comment: @Raphael: As long as you're not trying to do something that takes any time (such as contacting an external server, for example), then you should be fine.

Comment: What about writing to a file? Like a Sqlite file?

Comment: @Raphael: You are probably okay writing to a file. Of course, that will require testing with your OS.

Answer (score 18):

There is a signal from `QCoreApplication` (inherited by `QApplication`) called [`aboutToQuit`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#aboutToQuit) that is fired immediately before the application terminates.

Comment: How can i use this to prevent the app from closing if some activity is running ?

Comment: @pra16 You should ask that as a proper question.

Comment: Furthermore, it appears that code run from the `aboutToQuit` signal blocks the app closing until it is done, and therefore that code is guaranteed to run.